# Is there a word for making a change to something, expecting a change in outcome, but no change in outcome occurs?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

This is a phenomena I experience occasionally in programming when debugging. I will have a program that doesn't do what I want, so I make a change to the code expecting the program to do something different when I run it again. However, when I run the program again, I am surprised and frustrated to get the same result.

Comment: Sounds like your change was a ***[no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)***.

Comment: an ineffectual or abortive change

Comment: Not a single word, but an "[unexpected non-event](https://books.google.com/books?id=X76ibuZFILYC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22unexpected+non+event%22&source=bl&ots=Wq3eEeSEVA&sig=c1firIpd4TT8A0ed45sn8B68N3c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIr6DpzuahxwIVTG0-Ch3cAQFn#v=onepage&q=%22unexpected%20non%20event%22&f=false)" says it in two.

Comment: Peripheral to your question, I comment that phenomena is the plural of phenomenon and should not be used as a singular noun.

Comment: @Anton Ight I feel ya

Comment: If you do it over and over again it is called "insanity" (at least according to Albert Einstein).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word **[ineffectual](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ineffectual)** fits this well.

> **ineffectual**
>
> Not producing any or the desired effect

*'I thought by correcting the nested loop the error would be avoided, but it turned out to be ineffectual.'*

Comment: Even if *innefectual* is more widely used, I like **inefficient** or **ineffective**.